# Posting to my facebook page and twitter timeline offline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter, facebook-php-sdk, twitter-oauth

I've an app that lets user upload their pic, do some image manipulation using my app and then publish it which makes those images visible to public.

I now want to post the image to my facebook page's timeline and twitter as soon as any user publishes their photo.

Is it possible to do this even?
Is it possible to get permanent access token and not have to go thru OAuth thing.

I looked around on SO but couldn't find an answer close to what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes its possible, but you have to use access token of the user on behalf of whom you want to publish post on that page on facebook

Comment: Thanks :) Can you point me to some link/tutorial where I can read more about this? Sorry but I'm new to this.

Answer (score 1):

**Facebook:**

1. It uses OAuth2,so firstly you have to get an access token, the documentation can be referred [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/)
2. For making api calls using access token, `GET` and `POST` requests are to be made, as explained [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/)

**Twitter:**

1. It uses OAuth 1, so will get Access token and token secret , as explained [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth)
2. For api calls, you can refer [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1)

**Note:** Depending on the language you use, you can find relative sdks.

Comment: so I do have to go thru OAuth thingy. And these tokens are short-lived. So when token expires my app can not post anything to my facebook page or twitter timeline. isn't it? Do I've to manually renew this access token?

Comment: in twitter the token wont expire, in facebook it will expire after the period of 60 days or so, when you will retrieve an access token, you will get a refresh token also, with which you can renew your access token easily

Comment: and yes you have to use oauth only, no other option is there

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** You are talking about a user's fanpage not a user's wall right ?

To add to Jhanvi's answer here is a basic run down for facebook to get a permanent page access token:

1. Get user to allow app with appropriate permissions
2. Retreive user access token
3. Change user access token for extended user access token

Here is how I do this step (you could also use curl)

```
$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUT_APP_SECRET&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=OLD_TOKEN";
$accessToken = @file_get_contents($token_url);
```

Then

1. Query /me/accounts with user extended access token to get the page
2. Change page access token for extended access token (same code as above)

And you get a permanent access token that only expires if the user changes password or disallows the app.

The last step shouldn't be necessary according to the doc

Comment: Hi Tom, Yes I'm talking about Fan page and not his wall. To be specific, user has a page for his business and he is the admin of that page. I want to post on the wall of page.

Comment: Well use the above method to get an extended token for your page and store the page's id & extended token. Then all you'll have to do is retreive them and use them in your API call when a user publishes a pic. The php sdk is pretty well documented.